# Where does Sage store the codes?

Tags: python, sage

So I had a Ubuntu equipped laptop on which I was running Sage. I had Sage installed in it and I used to go to the terminal and go into the Sage's directory and run it from there by typing "./sage" and then go into the "notebook()" mode.

Now that laptop has crashed and I have the HDD separately with me. Now when I insert that HDD into a different computer and look into the files in that Sage folder, I can't locate my code files in it!

- Where in the HDD were my codes being saved?

Answer (score 1):

Typically Sage notebook stuff is saved separately from the notebook itself, intentionally.  Here is where it is on my laptop (Mac, not Ubuntu, but note I do start in the home directory):

```
$ ls .sage/sage_notebook.sagenb/home/
__store__   abc     guest       jmm12       pub
_sage_      admin       hihihi      new_user
$ cat .sage/sage_notebook.sagenb/home/admin/210/worksheet.html 


{{{id=1|
2+2
///
4
}}}

{{{id=2|
2-3
///
-1
}}}

<p>Hi there. &nbsp;Here is some math - $2+2=\int_0^4 1\, dx$.</p>

{{{id=3|

///
}}}

{{{id=4|
plot3d(x^1.5,(0,1),(0,1))
///
}}}

{{{id=5|

///
}}}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @kricsman Is this "/home/admin/210" an inbuilt sequence of folders or is this something you created?

Comment: That's just an example; however, every "normal" local user should have the `.sage/sage_notebook.sagenb/home/admin` and then all your worksheets would typically be in there.  The folder numbers for each worksheet are auto-generated, but it's clearly visible when you're in the notebook as the url.  If you have specific content you're looking for, I'd grep through the worksheet.html files to see where it is.  Hope this helped!